# This code returns unexpected identifier in the chrome console.But still this function works and returns the answer.Were have i gone wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to calculate the duration of the shift.It works well for foth day and night shift timings.But y does this returns error.In the console it returns unexpected identifier error but the code works and returns the answer.I think There might be an issue in the if part.But as far as i have seen,I couldnt find anything

```js
$("#formShiftEndTime").on("change", function() {
  var startHour = $("#formShiftStartTime").val();
  var endHour = $("#formShiftEndTime").val();
  calculate_time(startHour, endHour);
  //   console.log(startHour);
})


function showTime(hours, minutes) {
  return ((hours < 10) ? '0' : '') + hours +
    ':' +
    ((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes;
}

var startHour = $("#formShiftStartTime").val();
var endHour = $("#formShiftEndTime").val();

function calculate_time(formShiftStartTime, formShiftEndTime) {

  if (($("#formShiftStartTime").val()) < ($("#formShiftEndTime").val()))
  {
    startTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftStartTime);
    endTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftEndTime);
  } else {
    startTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftStartTime);
    endTime = new Date('1-2-1 ' + formShiftEndTime);
  }

  var difference = endTime - startTime;
  difference /= 1000 * 60; // convert to minutes
  var hours = Math.floor(difference / 60);
  var mins = Math.floor(difference % 60);

  document.getElementById('formDuration').value = showTime(hours, mins);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="calculate" action="">
  <div>
    <p><label>Start Hour: <input type="time" name="formShiftStartTime" id="formShiftStartTime"/></label></p>
    <p><label>End Hour: <input type="time" name="formShiftEndTime" id="formShiftEndTime" /></label></p>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Duration</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="formDuration" name="formDuration">

      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/y8ajhwx5/) the error, though doesn't give correct results either ...

Comment: the input should be in 24 hour format.If so,then it will give the correct result.If the shift start time is 09:00 and end time is 18:00 then the result will be 09:00. For night shift cases,if the start time is 22:00 and the end time is 08:00 then the result will be 10:00

Comment: When I run the StackSnippet (thanks to Satpal) or the linked fiddle, I get always "NaN:NaN" ... Notice, that the mentioned error doesn't occur, it has to come from another script on your page.